# Simple int condition in Bash doesn't make sense

Tags: linux, bash

```
x=23;
y=223;
if [[ $x < $y ]]
then
    echo "TRUE"
else
    echo "FALSE"
fi
```

So this always print FALSE even thought 23 is clearly less than 223. I am new to bash so I might be missing something obvious. I tried substituting $x and $y with their actually value and that means to work fine. Please send help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` performs lexicographic ordering of strings. To get numeric ordering, use `-lt`.

```
x=23;
y=223;
if [[ $x -lt $y ]]
then
    echo "TRUE"
else
    echo "FALSE"
fi
```

Or you can use an arithmetic expression instead of a conditional expression:

```
if (( $x < $y ))
```